# write csv file with double quotes for particular column not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, double-quotes

I'm trying to write a csv file using python csv writer.

In which one of the column value is enclosed in "" [double quotes] e.g. : 'col1' 'col2' "test", when I open the file in wordpad, the word test is expected as "test" but actual result is """test"""

can someone guide for this issue.

Sample snippet of my try out:

```
csvReader = csv.reader(iInputFile)
writer = csv.writer(open('one_1.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r\n')

for row in csvReader:
     rawRow = []
     rawRow.append('31-7-2014') #Appending Date
     rawRow.append(row[0])   #Appending data
     rawRow.append('\"'+'test'+'\"') 
     writer.writerow(rawRow)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try with this one

```
f_writ = open('one_4.csv', 'wb')
csvReader = csv.reader(iInputFile)
writer = csv.writer(f_writ, delimiter=',',
                lineterminator='\r\n',
                quotechar = "'"
                )

for row in csvReader:

    writer.writerow(['31-7-2014',row[0],'\"text\"'])

f_writ.close()
```

also i find very useful this link
http://pymotw.com/2/csv/, there are a lot of exemples

Comment: Thanks for the link, really useful. Your code works exactly as I want. But can you please explain it for my better understanding. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

Probably you need to play with parameters quoting and escapechar.

For example, modified code

```
csvReader = csv.reader(iInputFile)
writer = csv.writer(open('one_1.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')

for row in csvReader:
     rawRow = []
     rawRow.append('31-7-2014') #Appending Date
     rawRow.append(row[0])   #Appending data
     rawRow.append('\"'+'test'+'\"') 
     writer.writerow(rawRow)
```

will produce output like that:

```
31-7-2014,'col1',\"test\"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I just want string in double quotes. No any other character,not even space.

Answer (score 4):

More generally, if you need to save your CSV file with every column within double quotes

```
with open('Data/with_quotes.csv', 'wt') as fr:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fr, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    
    with open('without_quotes.csv', 'rt') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True, doublequote=False)

        for row in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the accepted answer from @GiovanniPi, is that the default is

```
quotechar= '"'
```

Because the expected output already has double quotes, this has to be changed to:

```
quotechar = "'"
```

I am not sure what you would do if you needed to have both single and double quotes as quotechar requires a 1-character string